# Ajax call in Chrome extension not working

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

Trying to send an ajax request in a chrome extension. I have confirmed the request returns a 200 response, it should just console.log to 'test'. I'm not sure if there's some async problems here? I have read chrome extension 'addListener' documentation.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell); //this is not working
  return true;
});
```

background.js

```
require('./modules/communicate.js');

var communicate = new Communicate();

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting === "hello") {

            response = communicate.talk('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', 'GET');

            sendResponse({
                farewell: response
            });
            return true; //doing this correctly?
        }
});
```

communicate.js

```
Communicate = function() {

    this.talk = function(url, method) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            success: function(result) {
                return result;
            }
        });
    };

};
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": { "128": "images/icon.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },
  "background": { "scripts": ["js/background.js"] },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "js": [ "js/content.js" ]
  }],
  "permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "js/*", "html/*", "css/*", "images/*" ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: what does your manifest look like?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: problem was async jquery call was not finished before trying to send message back to content.js

I used $.when() to help